# Gitlab interservice communication

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Hi does gitlab support interservice comminication. I found a question related to it [Gitlab-CI: Cross-service communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041101/gitlab-ci-cross-service-communication/) in this there is a link to gitlab issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1042. Issue seems to be closed so i think support should be there.

I have an image in which i run my server which needs to connect to a database. In CI I have set my server image and postgres image as services. But Server is not able to connect to the postgres service. I get

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "[MASKED]" to address: Name or service not known
```

I am able to connect to the database thorough CI. But not able to connect to database through my server. ie. not able to connect to another service from one service.

```yaml
task1:
  stage: Test
  services:
    - name: postgres:latest
      alias: postgres
    - name: serverImage
      alias: server
  variables:
    FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: "true"
    POSTGRES_DB: testdb
    POSTGRES_USER: testuser
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ""
    POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
  script: 
    - curl -i http://server:3000
```

I am using self-hosted runner shared runners.

Am just trying simple connection

```py
from sqlalchemy import *
url = 'postgresql://testuser:@postgres:5432/testdb'
engine = create_engine(url)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    pass
```

When i added sleep before the connection, the error log is gone but now when i send request with curl i get another error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to server port 4000: No route to host
```

Comment: Can you show the _full_ error/traceback your service provides as well as the relevant code and configuration? Are you using gitlab.com or self-hosted runner? Based on your job configuration, your services should be able to communicate with one another if you're using gitlab.com shared runners and your server image is configured correctly to talk to `postgres:5432` -- you may need to make sure you have appropriate wait/retry logic so make sure postgres is up and available.

Comment: Updated with more info. Am using self-hosted runners. When i run it in CI it is connecting with postgres. Am just having trouble when i run it as a service.
Have't added wait/retry logic.

Comment: OK when i added a sleep before connection the issue seems to be fixed. But now am getting

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to server port 4000: No route to host`

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure why you would get that error. It may have to do with your runner/system configuration or other environment factor, as I've tested the exact same job configuration on gitlab.com as working. Is it possible your service container died? Try replacing your server image with `strm/helloworld-http` image and using port regular http port (80) `curl http://server`

Comment: Yes that image is working fine.

Comment: In this case, it sounds like your server image is the issue in this case. It is exiting with some kind of error before your `curl` is executing.

Comment: I've gone ahead and added an answer. If this has been helpful, please consider accepting it as an answer to your question for the gitlab interservice communication. If you need additional help in getting your Python service image stable/working, I would suggest opening a separate question with details on the code for your HTTP service and Dockerfile for the image, and any error/job logs you may have available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Waiting for database to be ready

The issue with your server image connecting to the database service was caused because both services start up at the same time and the database may not be ready for connections by the time your service tries to connect. As discussed in the comments, adding retry/wait logic resolves this issue.

### Custom service is not stable

The following `No route to host` error in your job will occur because your service image is exiting or failing to start before your job/`curl` connects to it. You need to make sure that your server continues to run successfully in order to be reachable.

### Job configuration for inter-communication is correct

Your job configuration is correct, as evidenced by the fact that replacing it with the image `strm/helloworld-http` allows communication to work properly, as discussed in the comments. So, the communication between all the containers (job, server, database) has been established.